# iframe inner content auto adjust width of non-responsive site in full layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, width

I have creates iframe in wordpress with ready made theme,
my theme layout default maximum width is 1024px,

and my iframe width is 100% but still the site url which I have given in iframe still larger than my theme layout width, and I found scrollbar,

the site of given URL in iframe is non-responsive,

I want to auto adjust width of that url site as per my iframe width, if it makes non-responsive  than it acceptable,

I don't want to make larger of my theme layout width and also I don't also want to overflow = hidden,

I search and found too many solution but all about to make iframe adjustable base to inner content/site but my need is,

Is there any way to make inner content automatically 100% of my iframe ?

thank you for reading

Comment: i think there is no way to do this.

Comment: do you controll the site which is loaded in the iframe, if yes you could add a get param for width and retrieve it on de site in the iframe. Otherwise it ain't possible, the only option that comes close is to use the php file_get_contents(); function for example to copy the site html so you control it.

Comment: no, That site is not in my control.
isn't it possible through this side iframe code using css or jquery or other?

and thanks a lot for response...